# Adding a marker to GMaps (google maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, colorize

I'm trying to use this tool: http://software.stadtwerk.org/google_maps_colorizr/ to add colour to my google map, here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xUUxn/851/

The colour works fine, but now I can't seem to add any markers to it, I've tried putting this example code in:

```
map.addMarker({ 
  lat: -12.043333,
  lng: -77.028333,
  title: 'Lima',
  infoWindow: {
    content: '<p>HTML Content</p>'
  }
 });
```

But it doesn't seem to work, I'm not entirely sure where to put it or even if the references are correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to create a marker you need to do the following:

Demo forked from your example:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/xUUxn/852/

JS:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng( -12.043333,-77.028333),
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
    });
```

To add an info window overlay:

```
var contentString = '<div id="content"><h1>Overlay</h1></div>';
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
  });


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
```

Comment: The addListener is what you need in order to have the click work.

Comment: Is there a way to just add it straight to the map instead of creating a variable, I need to use this in a loop to create many pointers

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/xUUxn/857/  If you have other questions try to search for them (this is actually a very common question here) and/or pen a new question specific to your case.

Comment: I've tried doing this, but now the box doesn't disappear when you choose another one..

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
   map: map,
   title:"Hello World!"
});
```

In your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xUUxn/854/

Comment: is there any way I could add the little content box (I've updated my question). I need to use this in a loop to create many markers also

Comment: @dersvenhesse what if i have to add name instead of title?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a loop, by this using 'this' as second parameters to to infoWindow.open()

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow = new ....;
    infowindow.open(map,this);
});
```