# simple mark gmaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

i want to add "simple marker" on this code .. but i am so confuse about javascript

this is the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("mapa"));
                    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
                    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl(3));
                    map.setCenter( new GLatLng(-7.263372623252126, 112.75139808654785), 14,0);

                    GEvent.addListener(map,'mousemove',function(point)
                    {
                        document.getElementById('latspan').innerHTML = point.lat()
                        document.getElementById('lngspan').innerHTML = point.lng()  
                        document.getElementById('latlong').innerHTML = point.lat() + ', ' + point.lng()

                    });

                    GEvent.addListener(map,'click',function(overlay,point)
                    {
                        document.getElementById('latlongclicked').value = point.lat() + ', ' + point.lng()

                    });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this : [Adding a marker to GMaps (google maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907626/adding-a-marker-to-gmaps-google-maps)

Btw, you can try this

```
map.addMarker({
  lat: -12.043333,
  lng: -77.028333,
  title: 'Lima',
  click: function(e) {
    alert('You clicked in this marker');
  }
});
```

Or read the oficcial documentation : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=es-419